# Sending OTP for Register (React, node.js) without DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, one-time-password

I wanted to create a code to generate an OTP code while a user trying to register the web site. Once the user enters his details and click on register button it should create and otp and send it to the user. Ince the user enters the otp the registration process should go on.
this is my index.js file

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function createNewOTP(phone,otp,key="",expiresAfter=5,algorithm="sha256"){
    const ttl      = expiresAfter * 60 * 1000; //Expires after in Minutes, converteed to miliseconds
    const expires  = Date.now() + ttl; //timestamp to 5 minutes in the future
    const data     = `${phone}.${otp}.${expires}`; // phone.otp.expiry_timestamp
    const hashBase = crypto.createHmac(algorithm,key).update(data).digest("hex"); // creating SHA256 hash of the data
    const hash     = `${hashBase}.${expires}`; // Hash.expires, format to send to the user
    // you have to implement the function to send SMS yourself. For demo purpose. let's assume it's called sendSMS
    return hash;
}

function verifyOTP(phone,otp,hash,key="",algorithm="sha256"){
    if(!hash.match(".")) return false; // Hash should have at least one dot
    // Seperate Hash value and expires from the hash returned from the user(
    let [hashValue,expires] = hash.split(".");
    // Check if expiry time has passed
    let now = Date.now();
    if(now>expires) return false;
    // Calculate new hash with the same key and the same algorithm
    let data  = `${phone}.${otp}.${expires}`;
    let newCalculatedHash = crypto.createHmac(algorithm,key).update(data).digest("hex");
    // Match the hashes
    if(newCalculatedHash === hashValue){
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

module.exports = {
    createNewOTP,
    verifyOTP
}
```

this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "otp-without-db",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "Database less OTP verification with cryptography",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://git@github.com/theanam/otp-without-db.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "otp",
    "sms",
    "verification",
    "cryptography",
    "smsverify",
    "emailverify",
    "2fa"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "Anam Ahmed",
    "email": "me@anam.co"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/theanam/otp-without-db/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/theanam/otp-without-db#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "otp-generator": "^4.0.0",
    "otp-without-db": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

this is my test.js

```
const otpTool = require("./index");

const phone   = "8801751205455";
const key     = "verysecret";
const otp     = 1234;



let hash     = otpTool.createNewOTP(phone,otp,key);
let verified = otpTool.verifyOTP(phone,otp,hash,key);

console.log(`Your verification status is ${verified}`);
```

once I run this with "npm start" it gives me this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfzI6.png)

how can I runn this??

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm start`, npm references "scripts" key under your `package.json` file. Since you do not have a command with "start" as key, you are encountering this error.

add

```
"start" : "node <file_name>.js"
```

in your scripts json.

The "scripts" key in your `package.json` should look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "node test.js"
  }
```